# Using "Crtl + C" to copy an item from QTableWidget in QGIS, but get all attributes from a feature

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I am using PyQGIS to develop a table as a QGIS 3.4 plugin.

The table is created by QTableWidget and looks good.

The weird thing is when I try to copy (*Ctrl+C* keyboard shortcut) an item in the table, it indeed copies the whole feature, like *Copy Feature* action in the Identify Features tool.

Basically, the item is just a simple string. I really don't know why this behaviour happened.

e.g. in the screenshot below, I only copied the blue highlighted item. But when pasting, I got an output of all attributes of the corresponding feature.
I didn't implement any function related to the Copy functionality.

[image]

Same result as I can get from Copy Feature action.

[image]

My Script:

```
    self.ui.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.ui.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.ui.scrollArea.setWidget(self.ui.widget)
    self.ui.layout_VArea = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.ui.widget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setItalic(True)
    font.setPointSize(9)

    # use QtableWidget to create table
    self.ui.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.ui.widget)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    self.ui.layout_VArea.addWidget(self.ui.tableWidget)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(self.userFields[self.layer]))

    labels = [self.labels[self.layer].get(field, field) for field in self.userFields[self.layer]]
    print(labels) # a list of string
        
    self.ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)
    print(self.ui.tableWidget.selectionBehavior()) # 0 
    print(self.ui.tableWidget.selectionMode()) # 3
    # get how many rows in the values
    rows = len(values)

    # set table rows
    self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(rows)

    for indexRow, id in enumerate(values.keys()):
        rowString = list(map(str, values[id]))
        print(rowString) # a string list
        for indexColumn, item in enumerate(rowString):
            flags = Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
            qItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(item)
            qItem.setFlags(flags)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(indexRow, indexColumn, qItem)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the issue for some time, I finally found out why this happend.

**Explain:**

The weird behaviour was caused by QGIS. Actually, there is a global shortcut for "Control+C" to copy the selected features on the map canvas.

The table is joined to features on the map, so when I click an item on the form, a feature is also selected.
Therefore, when clicking "Control+C", QGIS will query the whole feature's attributes instead of copying the single item.

That's the reason why this issue happened.

**Solution:**

You can disable 'Copy Feature' shortcut(Ctrl+C).

In QGIS, Setting -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Copy Feature -> Set None